# Jailbroken iPad enters safe mode while Wi-Fi syncing

Tags: ipad, itunes, data-synchronization, ios, crash

When I arrive at my house, I manually start Wi-Fi Sync (Settings > General > iTunes Wi-Fi Sync > Sync Now) to back up my data. But sometimes my iPad crashes into Safe Mode during this process.

I looked through the error log (Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage > Data > LatestCrash.plist) and it was constantly referring to `libsystem_kernel.dylib`, which is making me think that this might be caused by my tethered jailbreak.

Does anyone else have this problem, and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Safe Mode? There is no such thing. Could you explain further?

Comment: @VxJasonxV I'm referring to MobileSubstrate's safe mode feature on jailbroken devices.

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch the 'tethered jailbreak' line. My apologies.

Comment: It's something you've installed through Cydia or MobileSubstrate itself. Note MobileSubstrate has nothing to do with the jailbreak and is only installed to add functionality to 3rd party apps outside of Apple's ecosystem.

Comment: @cksum I know that MS is separate from the jailbreak, but I was saying `libsystem_kernel.dylib` might be what's crashing SpringBoard.

Comment: Hardly. Just because a crash report references a component doesn't mean it's the cause. You'll notice that all crashes reference both libsystem_c.dylib and libsystem_kernel.dylib quite frequently. That's not how you read a crash report. You have to look at exception type (whether it's a SIGSEV, SIGBUS, etc.) and exception codes and trace those back to the root. But like I said, if it's SpringBoard crashing, then it's MS or a plug-in tied to MS. SB doesn't crash unless you pollute it with MS and the stuff from Cydia. And certainly nothing to do with the tethered jailbreak.

Comment: @cksum Wi-Fi sync also occasionally crashes during safe mode for some reason. But if you'll put your message in an answer, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'd rather not as it's not an answer. An answer would be actually finding the exact cause of the crash and I've done no such thing, just explained likely causes. If you find the app that's causing the problems, you can answer your own question and then mark it as the correct one after a couple of days (time limit imposed by the system).

Comment: @cksum I've just set up `syslogd` so I'm going to check what happens there when I sync.